# Quickest way to solve PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I had an exam question to solve this PDE:
$$
 u_{xx}+9u_{yy}=0
$$
I tried solving this question in the exam by the separation of variables method assuming it would be the easiest one and found the solution to be:
$$
 u=F(x).G(y)=(c_1+c_2e^{kx})(c_3+c_4e^{-ky/9})
$$
But apparently it is incorrect. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Change of variables $ y \rightarrow 3 y $, which then reduces it to the laplacian. It's not clear what is meant by solve. Were boundary conditions given?

Comment: No conditions were given.

Comment: Is it possible by Laplace transformation?

Comment: @NipeshKc: Usually the Laplace transform is used for functions of a single variable. Furthermore, this method is computationally-intensive, not the best to use in a timed exam.

Comment: Perhaps solution by separation of variables is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing variable $y\to 3y$ we get $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$ this means $u$ is harmonic. Every harmonic function with this form has a solution $u(z)=h(z)+\overline{g(z)}$ where $h(z)$ and $g(z)$ are analytic functions.